# Please welcome your new pro tem moderators

Tags: discussion, moderators, announcements

For those who don't know me, I'm Pops, one of the Community Managers at Stack Exchange. I'm here with news of a big change today. Two of your existing moderators, Ankit Sharma and Mr. Alien, have asked to step down.

There are many passionate users on this site, and as a result, it's been difficult trying to pick the best possible replacements for them. Nevertheless, I'm happy to announce that you will be seeing diamonds next to the names of two familiar users very soon:

[image: Pandya]
[image: The Destroyer]

Please join me in thanking Ankit and Mr. Alien for their service and welcoming Pandya and The Destroyer!

Answer (score 19):

Happy to know that Pandya and The Destroyer are the new moderators of Hinduism.SE. Both are good when it comes to decision making and knowledge. Am sure you guys will make good moderators. Wish you luck. Feel free to ping me anytime if you want any help with moderator tools or something similar :)

Feels bad to step down as a moderator for almost after 3 years of moderating on Hinduism.SE, however, my hands are rusty now to drive Hinduism.SE, hence, opted to step out. Sorry if I or my actions unintentionally hurt you.

Looking forward to a change :) Wish you a happy moderation.

P.S Feels odd to see my name without a diamond :p

Comment: Yeah your name surely does look odd without a diamond :).

Comment: Btw, thanks for your moderation which helped this community to have a basic structure.

Comment: @Mr_Green thank you bro

Answer (score 17):

Congratulations [Pandya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/277/pandya) and [The Destroyer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/3500/the-destroyer). I wish you all the best. Sorry for steeping down like this, have other priority in life. I will surely be present as a muggle ;) here and will still try to help whenever possible.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks for the honor of assisting the moderation of this site. Since joining this site, I'm in love with Hinduism SE! I learned a lot about Dharma from this site and i'm feeling happy now to contribute for moderation of this site and that too on auspicious night of Mahashivaratri (Just after beginning of  Chaturdasi Tithi before Lingodhbhava time. Sorry for too much of jargon :P).

You can contact me on our site room [Hinduism](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism), if you have any problem. I will try to respond to you as soon as possible.

Finally, I would like to thank [Ankit Sharma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/76/ankit-sharma?tab=profile) and [Mr Alien](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/124/mr-alien?tab=profile) for their contribution to moderation of this site.

Comment: Congratulations Destroyer & @Pandya ..:)

Comment: Ok ..i will surely try..thanks for asking..

Comment: Congrats guys!! you guys deserve to be Mod for your frequent activity on this site.

Comment: Congratulations again :D

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations and best wishes to both of you !

Comment: lol someone downvoted this too :D

Comment: @Mr_Green Really? :-D  Someone really hates me or the mods :-)

Comment: I don't know really who it is.. just don't think they hate you it is just they dislike your post. :)

Comment: @Mr_Green Oh they hate ME. If they disliked the post, then they must hate the  mods that I am welcoming  :-D